# MATLAB: Looping Through a Cell Array

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

In MATLAB, I have a csv file with the data (ignore whitespaces below only for readable):

```
State,  Rain, Sunshine,
Indiana,  52,    25,
Kansas,   45,    22,
Georgia   35,    55,
Texas     22,    30,
Arizona   60,    12,
```

I need to create a for loop that will step through the cell array State:

```
   State = {'Indiana','Kansas','Georgia','Texas','Arizona'}
   for n = 1:numel(states)
```

and generate a separate plot for Rain vs. Sunshine for each state.

Thanks,

Amanda

Comment: Do you need to read the CSV as well, or do you have the data stored in variables? Also, you only have 1 data point for Rain and Sunshine for each state, so how will you generate separate plots for each state?

Comment: Data is already stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you require, but this will plot the Rain and Sunshine of each state.

```
Rain = [52,45,35,22,60];
Sunshine = [25,22,55,30,12];
State = {'Indiana','Kansas','Georgia','Texas','Arizona'};

figure
hold on
for n = 1:numel(State)
plot(Rain(n),Sunshine(n),'.')
text(Rain(n),Sunshine(n),State(n))
end
xlabel('Rain')
ylabel('Sunshine')
```

With this result:

[image: Plot of rain v sunshine]